# Sending DATA to FPGA

Tags: serial-port, usb, fpga, ethernet, hdl

I am working on a project which requires data to be sent  FROM PC TO FPGA,which processes the data and sends it BACK TO PC. 
 The board I am using is Atlys™ Spartan-6 FPGA Development Board.
 The data is to be sent as 1 byte , because 1 byte is processed at each rising edge of the clock.
 Could you please suggest me ways of sending data to FPGA ?
Thanks

Comment: UART, USB, PCIe, QPI, Ethernet... there are many.

Answer (score 2):

Pick some method of communication that you have access to IP (intellectual property) cores for.  For example, if you can readily access a UDP/IP core for your FPGA, then use that.  If you have to develop the HDL yourself, serial protocols (UART, I2C, etc) will be simpler blocks to write.  In general, HDL takes longer to develop, debug, and test.

UDP has some advantage because you can use tools like Wireshark to capture packets on the PC (once you get past the initial hurdle of actually getting packets to/from the FPGA).  Plus, many people are familiar with UDP in various programming languages (C, C++).

In any case, you'll probably spend time with an oscilloscope and logic analyzer checking out signal levels and timing when data is sent to/from the FPGA.

Comment: Thank you . By the way could you guide me in sending real time data to fpga using simulink ? I have been searching on net and I must say it is a very good and simple idea to use simulink for capturing image and then using fpga as a hardware accelerator and displaying image using Matlab. Could you please guide me here ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not all that familiar with Simulink for serial communication.